# Disabling Windows hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a binding where if I hold right click, it will also hold the left ctrl and left alt buttons.

On top of this, I would like to add some conditions that prevent me from doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (in this case holding right click and pressing tab) or doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. For these two conditions, I would just like to insert the raw key press, either <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The problem is that although trying many different ways to go about this, the script still reads my input as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> rather than <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Here is my script:

```
#IfWinActive Guild Wars 2
#NoEnv
#Warn
SendMode Input

RButton::
    Send {RButton down}
    Send {LCtrl down}
    Send {LAlt down}
    while(GetKeyState("RButton","P")){
        if(GetKeyState("Tab", "P")){
            Send {LCtrl up}
            Send {LAlt up}
            Send {Tab}
            Send {LCtrl down}
            Send {LAlt down}
        }
        else if(GetKeyState("Esc", "P")){
            Send {LCtrl up}
            Send {LAlt up}
            Send {Esc}
            Send {LCtrl down}
            Send {LAlt down}
        }
    }
    KeyWait RButton
    Send {RButton up}
    Send {LCtrl up}
    Send {LAlt up}

#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a delay before sending `Tab`/`Esc`:

```
Send {LCtrl up}
Send {LAlt up}

Sleep 1
Send {Tab}

Send {LCtrl down}
Send {LAlt down}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed such a small thing was causing a big issue. Thank you so much. Do you know why it is necessary to have sleep after the ctrl+alt release? Is it because it will try to do them all at once?

Comment: I guess it's because without the delay the `up` events are somehow merged with the main key press event.